# Many null entries when parse a json

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I have a json like this in a server and I want to get the "challenge_id" and "rendered" data:

[image]

I try to deserialize it with SimpleJson like this:

```
void Start()
{
    string url = "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

    WWW www = new WWW(url);
    StartCoroutine(WaitForRequest(www));
}
IEnumerator WaitForRequest(WWW www)
{
    yield return www;
    if (www.error == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("WWW Ok!: " + www.text);
        string jsonString = www.text;
        var N = JSON.Parse(jsonString);

        if (name == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("No data converted");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log(N[1]["title"]["rendered"]);
            Debug.Log(N[1]["acf"]["challenge_id"]);

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonString.Length; i++)
            {
                Debug.Log(N[i]["title"]["rendered"]);
                Debug.Log(N[i]["acf"]["challenge_id"]);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("WWW Error: " + www.error);
    }
}
```

But when I play the game the console shows all the "rendered" and "challenge_id" data and many other entries with "null".

"Prueba 2 Piratas Challenges"
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
"5c2c8da810dd2304e3d3bcd9"
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
"Prueba Challenge Piratas"
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
"5c24cfa46315fb04ff78c02c"
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
"prueba carambola"
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
"5c24cacd6315fb04ff6fce22"
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
null
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
null
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
null
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
null
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
null
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance !

Comment: Can you please replace the images of text with actual text? This makes it easier for people with similar problems to find this question. It also makes the question easier to read, discuss, and answer, especially for folks who use screen readers. Anyway, why are you looping until `i < jsonString.Length`? Wouldn't `i < N.Count` make more sense?

Comment: I'd personally suggest using NewtonSoft to handle your JSON.  It's a Nuget package you can get.  It handles deserializing and serializing very easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are iterating over

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonString.Length; i++)
{
    Debug.Log(N[i]["title"]["rendered"]);
    Debug.Log(N[i]["acf"]["challenge_id"]);
}
```

so this block runs `jsonString.Length` times ... which means for every **character** in the original `jsonString`.

It is not iterating over the length of `N` - the collection you want to loop.

---

So instead use

```
for (int i = 0; i < N.Count; i++)
{
    Debug.Log(N[i]["title"]["rendered"]);
    Debug.Log(N[i]["acf"]["challenge_id"]);
}
```

or to avoid any mistakes of this kind

```
foreach(var n in N)
{
    Debug.Log(n["title"]["rendered"]);
    Debug.Log(n["acf"]["challenge_id"]);
}
```

---

However I would actually expect that you get an IndexOutOfRangeException when you try to access `N[i]` if `i => N.Length` ... but maybe this is handled different in [SimpleJSON](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON).

**Update**

I found that the `JSONObject` class there has the following implementation:

```
public override JSONNode this[int aIndex]
{
    get
    {
        if (aIndex < 0 || aIndex >= m_Dict.Count)
            return null;
        return m_Dict.ElementAt(aIndex).Value;
    }
    set
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

as you can see they simply return `null` if the index is out of range.